# Create Android background service and keep XMPP connection alive and packet listener set when app is closed

Tags: android, xmpp

I am creating a chat application. For this, I am testing out a XMPP server. On login, I connect and login to the test XMPP server. It is sending and receiving messages.

What I want is, when the app is closed (on destroy method called), this service should keep the connection alive and listen to messages and store them in the same database that the app is using.

I have created a service and added connection listener and packet listener to it but as soon as I close the app, I see the service running but the connection is lost.

Login Activity:

```
private class ProcessLogin extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String uname,password;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        uname = txtUsername.getText().toString();
        password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Contacting Servers");
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Create a connection
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST,PORT);
        XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
        String user = null;

        HostAddress address = new HostAddress(HOST);

        try {
            try {
                connection.connect();

            } catch (SmackException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
            Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "+ address.getErrorMessage());

        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());
            Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "+ address.getErrorMessage());
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
            //setConnect(null);
        }
        try {
            try {
                connection.login(uname, password);
                XMPPSuper.getInstance().setConnection(connection);
            } catch (SaslException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SmackException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "Logged in as" + connection.getUser());




            // Set the status to available
            Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);

            connection.sendPacket(presence);
            //setConnect(connection);

            Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
            Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
            for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "--------------------------------------");
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "User: " + entry.getUser());
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Name: " + entry.getName());
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Type: " + entry.getType());
                Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "+ entryPresence.getStatus());
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: " + entryPresence.getType());

                Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
                if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                    Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : " + entryPresence);
                user = XMPPSuper.getInstance().getConnection().getUser();
            }
        } catch (XMPPException ex) {
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "+  USERNAME);
            Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
            user=null;
            //setConnect(null);
        }
        //                 dialog.dismiss();
        catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return user;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String user) {
        try {

            if(user != null){

                // Creating user login session
                // For testing i am storing name, email as follow
                // Use user real data

                session.createLoginSession(user,"email id", "2000");

                Intent i = new Intent("com.example.tabmainactivity");
                pDialog.dismiss();
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), iFlyChatMessage.class));
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }else{
                // username / password doesn't match
                pDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Incorrect username/password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

My service:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {

    connection = XMPPSuper.getInstance().getConnection();
    //PingManager keep_alive = PingManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
    configureConnection(connection);
    //keep_alive.setPingInterval(100);

    if (connection != null) {

        final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        // Add a packet listener to get messages sent to us
        PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message.Type.chat);
        connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message message = (org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message) packet;
                if (message.getBody() != null) {
                    String fromName = StringUtils.parseBareAddress(message.getFrom());
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity ", " Text Recieved " + message.getBody() + " from " + fromName);


                    java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
                    Timestamp time = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
                    db.addMessage(message.getBody().toString(), fromName, "testkerry@suchat.org", "1", "2000", time.toString());
                    /*org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message msg = new org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message(fromName);
                    msg.setBody("Test Successful");
                    try {
                        connection.sendPacket(msg);

                    } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }*/
                    // Add the incoming message to the list view
                    /*mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            //    setListAdapter();
                        }
                    });*/
                    //messagelist.add(new MessageClass("kerry@suchat.org","testkerry@suchat.org",recipient_uid, sender_uid,message.getBody().toString(), time.toString()));


                }
            }
        }, filter);
    }

}

/** The service is starting, due to a call to startService() */
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}



private void configureConnection(final XMPPConnection connection){
    connection.addConnectionListener(new AbstractConnectionListener()
                                     {

                                         public void connectionClosed(){

                                             connect();




                                         }
                                         public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e)
                                         {

                                             connect();
                                         }

                                         public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e)
                                         {
                                         }
                                         public void reconnectionSuccessful(){
                                         }
                                         public void reconnectingIn(int seconds)
                                         {
                                         }
                                     }
    );
}

private void connect()
{
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST,PORT);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);

    HostAddress address = new HostAddress(HOST);

    try {
        try {
            connection.connect();

        } catch (SmackException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "+ address.getErrorMessage());

    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "[SettingsDialog] Connected to "+ address.getErrorMessage());
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
        //setConnect(null);
    }
    try {
        try {
            connection.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD);
            XMPPSuper.getInstance().setConnection(connection);
        } catch (SaslException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SmackException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "Logged in as" + connection.getUser());




        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);

        connection.sendPacket(presence);
        //setConnect(connection);

        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {

            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity",  "--------------------------------------");
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "RosterEntry " + entry);
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "User: " + entry.getUser());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Name: " + entry.getName());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Status: " + entry.getStatus());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Type: " + entry.getType());
            Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());

            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "+ entryPresence.getStatus());
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: " + entryPresence.getType());

            Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();
            if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : " + entryPresence);
        }
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "+  USERNAME);
        Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
        //setConnect(null);
    }
    //                 dialog.dismiss();
    catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Any idea how to go about it?

Comment: can you post your code what you tried?

Comment: @Rakesh I have added my code. Please have a look. I am a bit new so the code might be really bad quality

Answer (score 1):

when started your application start the service

add connection listener and packet listener inside AsyncTask's `onPostExecute()` method.

and execute `AsyncTask` inside service `onCreate()` method

executing `AsyncTask` inside service it keeps the task work continuously up to service alive and also xmpp connection.

i hope it will help you

it works for me...

Comment: Well, actually I solved the problem. I am connecting it in service but on a separate thread. I think you method will work but if I kill my app, i notice that service restarts, when the service restarts, will it be able to access the Asynctask written in activity? Thanks for the answer by the way :)

Comment: write AsyncTask in separate class file because you need every time while network changes

Comment: @kerry is this updated post with your working solution..?

Comment: @NikhilBorad No, I should have posted the solution but I think I do not have access to the code now as it was a year back and I was working somewhere else.

Comment: @kerry How did you solve this problem? Can you explain it if you still remember?

Comment: @Zookey it was a long time back when i tries this. Unfortunately, I do not have access to the code nor do I remember how I solved it